# Can I use stack bar plot and hue together in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to build a bar plot which is categorized by hue and also stacked based on other column as well in seaborn. Is it possible to do that ?  Example is given below. Sometimes in my hue,there can also be sub categories which I want to stack for that hue value. Please help me in that. I have been doing hue based bar chart as below

```
ax = sns.barplot(data = sample,
        x='xval',y='check', hue='cat')
```

[image: based on Hue]

[image: based on stacking column chart]